# increment in the function name and id javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops, for-loop

I have number of input types and buttons....every button on click increment the value in the relevant input types. But rather than creating a separate function for every button i want to do it by loop....where loop will increase in the function name and id......

```
    <input type="number" id="s1"> <button onclick="increment_s1();">Add</button>
    <input type="number" id="s2"> <button onclick="increment_s2()">Add</button>
    <input type="number" id="s3"> <button onclick="increment_s3">Add</button>
```

here is JavaSc code

```
<script>
  var i = 1;
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
var data = 0;
document.getElementById("s"+i).innerText = data; 
function ['increment_'+i]() {
    data = data + 1;
    document.getElementById("s"+i).placeholder = data;
     i++;
}
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't program the function name. You can set up a parameter in the function to make a difference. The param would be the identifier and you can put the whole `input` element id there.

After that, if you want to have the id `s1`, `s2`, and so on, you should initialize the `i` to start from 1 to 5 instead of 0 to less than 5.

Another thing is, you need to understand the role of `placeholder` and `value` attributes in `input` element. The `placeholder` works only when the `value` is empty and it doesn't count as the form value.

```js
// This is for handling onclick 
function increment(id) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    elem.value = parseInt(elem.value) + 1;
}
// This is to initialize the 0 values
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  var data = 0;
  document.getElementById("s"+i).value = data;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="s1"> <button onclick="increment('s1');">Add</button>
<input type="number" id="s2"> <button onclick="increment('s2')">Add</button>
<input type="number" id="s3"> <button onclick="increment('s3')">Add</button>
<input type="number" id="s4"> <button onclick="increment('s4')">Add</button>
<input type="number" id="s5"> <button onclick="increment('s5')">Add</button>
```

What if you would like to generate whole `input` and `button` with loops? You can get them by adding `div` and use the `innerHTML`, i.e.

```js
// This is for handling onclick 
function increment(id) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    elem.value = parseInt(elem.value) + 1;
}

var divElem = document.querySelector('div');

// Set up empty first
divElem.innerHTML = "";

for(var i=1; i<=5; i++) {
  // Create elements here
  var innerElem = `<input type="number" id="s${i}" value="0"> <button onclick="increment('s${i}')">Add</button>`;
  
  // Push them all into innerHTML
  divElem.innerHTML += innerElem;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

You can try these two workarounds. Perhaps you may need to learn more about basic HTML elements and their attributes also Javascript.